# Getting a Form's Icon when I know the Form's handle

Tags: windows, delphi, icons

I am trying to get the Icon of a form, and set it to my own app's Icon. I found this code, however it does not really work for me:

```
  MyIcon := TIcon.Create;
   Try
   MyIcon.Handle := MyHandle;
   MyForm.Icon := MyIcon;
   Finally
     MyIcon.Free;
   End;
 end;
```

I tried opening an app that I know has a specific Icon, I find it's handle, but the Icon that is shown in my app, is the default Windows exe one.

Any ideas?

Comment: (1) Is the 'form' a form in your own application, or a window in an external application? (2) Do you only need to obtain the icon, or do you need to *change* the icon of the form (possibly in the external application)?

Comment: The MyForm is my own form. I need to change MY icon :)

Comment: But if it is your own form, then, surely, you can do just `MyForm.Icon := MyIcon` or `MyForm.Icon.LoadFromFile()` or ...?

Comment: OK, I think I see now. By "set it to my own..." I first thought that you wanted to change the icon just found, but instead, you want to use that particular icon as your own icon, right? You mean "set it **as** my own...".

Comment: The code above doesn't work because after `MyForm.Icon := MyIcon` the `MyForm.Icon` and `MyIcon` are the same object. So when you free `MyIcon`, you also free `MyForm.Icon`. You should use `MyForm.Icon.Assign(MyIcon)` instead. Or simply do `MyForm.Icon.ReleaseHandle` followed by `MyForm.Icon.Handle := HandleOfTheExternalIcon` which you get by sending a `WM_GETICON` message to the external window. That is, you use `WM_GETICON` to get the `HICON` of the `HWND`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question in the title of your post:

To obtain a `TIcon` from a `HWND`, that is, to obtain the icon associated with a window (not necessarily in your own application), do something like

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  HIco: HICON;
  Icon: TIcon;
begin
  HIco := SendMessage(Handle, WM_GETICON, ICON_BIG, 0);
  if HIco = 0 then
    HIco := SendMessage(Handle, WM_GETICON, ICON_SMALL2, 0);
  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    Icon.ReleaseHandle;
    Icon.Handle := HIco;
    // Do something with Icon, for instance
    Canvas.Draw(10, 10, Icon);
  finally
    Icon.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To use the icon of the `HWND` window as the icon of your own form, do

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  HWin: HWND;
  HIco: HICON;
begin
  HWin := FindWindow(nil, 'New file'); // A Rejbrand Text Editor window
  HIco := SendMessage(HWin, WM_GETICON, ICON_BIG, 0);
  if HIco = 0 then
    HIco := SendMessage(HWin, WM_GETICON, ICON_SMALL2, 0);
  Self.Icon.ReleaseHandle; // important!
  Self.Icon.Handle := HIco;
end;
```